# Erro "Argument of type is not assignable to" em função com parâmetros rest no TypeScript

Tags: typescript, tipagem

Tenho um tipo `Role` que deve ser uma chave do objeto roles e uma função que retorna todas as chaves:

```
export type Role = keyof typeof roles;

export function allRoles(): Role[] {
  return Object.keys(roles) as Role[];
}
```

E o seguinte decorador:

```
export const Roles = (...roles: Role[]) => setMetadata('roles', roles);
```

Porém, ao tentar usar o decorador como `@Roles(allRoles())`, o TypeScript informa que há erro nos tipos:

> Argument of type '('Role1', 'Role2')' não é atribuível ao parâmetro do tipo 'Role1 | Role2'.

Comment: O que é essa função `Roles`? Poderia [edit] a pergunta para incluir sua assinatura?

Comment: Adicionei, a função Roles simplesmente adiciona o roles no metadata

Comment: O que você quer que `Roles` receba, de fato? Um array cujos elementos sejam as chaves de `roles`?

Comment: Exatamente, `Roles` deve receber uma array de Roles, os itens dessa array são chaves de um objeto, que no caso é o `keyof typeof roles`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que o tipo `Role[]` é diferente do tipo esperado pela construção `(...roles: Role[])`.

O tipo `Role[]` significa qualquer array cujos elementos sejam atribuíveis ao tipo `Role`.

Já `(...roles: Role[])` é uma construção sintática que é usada para definir o tipo de uma função que aceita **[parâmetros *rest*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#rest-parameters-and-arguments)**, isto é, uma função com [aridade](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aridade) variada.

Isso significa que a função não aceita um array no primeiro argumento (como você está passando), mas sim um número variado de argumentos do tipo `Role` que, em conjunto, formam um array do tipo `Role[]`.

Então você precisa mudar o tipo da função, de modo que deixe de ser uma função variádica:

```
function Roles(...roles: Role[]) {
  // ...
}
```

Tornando-a uma função que aceita apenas um argumento – um array de `Role`s:

```
function Roles(roles: Role[]) {
  // ...
}
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATiANgUwjAvDA3gWAFAwwBmIIAXDFHAK7IA0%20hARgIZwVW34C%20A3PvigBPAA7IYAJSTjMAa2RCQRSqORL40iPzz4i1MMCgBLcDBaJEUlBAAUASgpXkAbQC62RvGRRqcMDAB5JgArZEMAOnkhWwRrOzM0JzdtbgE8PQNjUycYzUdpN3jcAhgAelKYcKqeNPLAgGkYGwhkAFsYZDgECAd8HJtzS017O14gA).</sup>

---

Uma outra opção seria utilizar `Function.prototype.apply` ou o operador de espalhamento no retorno de `getRoles()`, mas semanticamente falando, não acredito que sejam corretas. Mudar o tipo esperado da função, nesse caso, parece-me o mais adequado.